# Vuex передача нескольких массивов

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Имеется фильтр компонент,в нем кнопки с чекбоском. При нажатии на кнопку, апи даёт 20 товаров этой категории. И выводятся на странице.
**Компонент**

```
this.$store.commit(
 'showFilteredList',
  response.data.items
);
```

**filter.js**

```
state: {
 filteredBrands: []
},

mutations: {
  showFilteredList(state, payload) {
   if(payload.length < 1) {
     console.log('clear');
   } else {
     state.filteredBrands = payload;
   }
  }
}
```

Проблема в том, что если я выбираю еще 1 чекбокс - то прилетают другие товары из категории, прошлые перезатираются `state.filteredBrands = payload;`, связано с этой строкой. Но пушить не выходит.
В целом, хотелось бы, чтобы при выборе двух и  более чекбоксов товары выводили на странице, если чекбокс снят у какого либо - товары убирались.

Что нужно изменить или добавить?

Answer (score 1):

предположим что в данных которые приходят с бека есть ключ category, это позволит привязывать значения чекбокса к этому ключу и уже исходя из этого можно реализовать нужную логику.
При получении данных я бы использовал spread оператор, который позволит добавлять значения в уже имеющийся массив

```
showFilteredList(state, payload) {
   if(payload.length < 1) {
     return
   } 

  state.filteredBrands = [...state.filteredBrands, payload];
  }
```

потом при снятии галочки с выбранного чекбокса я бы вызывал мутацию, которая бы фильтровала массив с переданным значением чекбокса

```
deleteCheckboxItems(state, checkBoxValue) {
state.filteredBrands = state.filteredBrands.filter((item) => item.category !== checkBoxValue)
  }
```

Comment: Я немного изменил, то, что вы предложили. Теперь товары появляются и убираются со страницы. Но Только для первого массива, то есть, если выбрать два ```checkbox```, то первый будет убираться, а второй нет, с ошибкой ```Duplicate keys```